# How to convert this sql query to mongodb

Tags: sql, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Considering this query written in sql server how would I efficiently convert it to mongodb:

```
select * from thetable where column1 = column2 * 2
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use below aggregation.

You project a new field `comp` to calculate the expression value followed by `$match` to keep the docs with eq(0) value and `$project` with exclusion to drop `comp` field.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
   { $addFields: {"comp": {$cmp: ["$column1",  {$multiply: [ 2, "$column2" ]} ]}}},
   { $match: {"comp":0}},
   { $project:{"comp":0}}
])
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to run your query in mongo Shell,
try below code,

```
db.thetable .find({}).forEach(function(tt){
    var ttcol2 = tt.column2 * 2
    var comapreCurrent =  db.thetable.findOne({_id : tt._id,column1 : ttcol2});
    if(comapreCurrent){
       printjson(comapreCurrent);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I liked the answer posted by @Veeram but it would also be possible to achieve this using $project and $match pipeline operation.
This is just for understanding the flow

Assume we have the below 2 documents stored in a **math** collection

***Mongo Documents***

```
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("58a055b52f67a312c3993553"),
        "num1" : 2,
        "num2" : 4
    }

    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("58a055be2f67a312c3993555"),
        "num1" : 2,
        "num2" : 6
    }
```

Now we need to find if num1 = 2 times of num2 (In our case the document with _id ObjectId("58a055b52f67a312c3993553") will be matching this condition)

***Query:***

```
    db.math.aggregate([
      {
        "$project": {
          "num2": {
            "$multiply": ["$num2",1]
          },
          "total": {
            "$multiply": ["$num1",2]
          },
          "doc": "$$ROOT"
        }
      },
      {
        "$project": {
          "areEqual": {"$eq": ["$num2","$total"]
          },
          doc: 1
        }
      },
      {
        "$match": {
          "areEqual": true
        }
      },
      {
        "$project": {
          "_id": 1,
          "num1": "$doc.num1",
          "num2": "$doc.num2"
        }
      }
    ])
```

***Pipeline operation steps:-***

- The 1st pipeline operation $project calculates the total
- The 2nd pipeline operation $project is used to check if the total
  matches the num2. This is needed as we cannot use the comparision
  operation of num2 with total in the $match pipeline operation
- The 3rd pipeline operation matches if areEqual is true
- The 4th pipeline operation $project is just used for projecting the fields

***Note:-***
In the 1st pipeline operation I have multiplied num2 with 1 as num1 and num2 are stored as integers and $multiply returns double value. So incase I do not use $mutiply for num2, then it tries to match 4 equals 4.0 which will not match the document.

Answer (score 0):

Certainly no need for multiple pipeline stages when a single **[`$redact`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/#pipe._S_redact)** pipeline will suffice as it beautifully incorporates the functionality of **[`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/#pipe._S_project)** and **[`$match`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/#pipe._S_match)** pipeline steps. Consider running the following pipeline for an efficient query:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    { 
        "$redact": { 
            "$cond": [
                { 
                    "$eq": [ 
                        "$column1", 
                        { "$multiply": ["$column2", 2] }
                    ] 
                },
                "$$KEEP",
                "$$PRUNE"
            ]
        }
    }
])
```

In the above, **[`$redact`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/#pipe._S_redact)** will return all documents that match the condition using **[`$$KEEP`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/#keep)** and discards those that don't match using the **[`$$PRUNE`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/#prune)** system variable.